# Why can't I upload a portfolio to Yahoo Finance?

Tags: portfolio, yahoo-finance

I used to be able to upload a new portfolio to Yahoo Finance by, while logged in, going to

- https://finance.yahoo.com/portfolios

clicking "Import", and submitting a CSV file. But when I do that now, I get the error message:

> There was some error while importing your portfolio. Please Try Again.

I never found any documentation of the structure of CSV file it requires, but the structure that I found worked in the past was:

```
| Symbol | Trade Date | Quantity | Purchase Price | Commission | 
| AAPL   | 2024 02 04 | 100      | 200            | 0          | 
| MSFT   | 2024 02 04 | 100      | 400            | 0          | 
| GOOG   | 2024 02 04 | 100      | 150            | 0          |
```

I submitted a test file with those contents and the filename "yahootest.csv" and got the above error message.

Has uploading portfolios been disabled, or am I doing something wrong?

---

Edit: A comment asked if I asked Yahoo Support about this. Yes. Not only that, but I signed up for a support subscription for about $5 a month, hoping that would get better attention. Without going into my files to dig out exactly what happened, I remember that the series of responses were completely useless, and I cancelled the subscription.

I can't be the only person who is experiencing this new inability to upload a portfolio. I'm surprised that searching neither Google nor Stack Exchange brings up anything useful about that error message.

Comment: Have you asked Yahoo's support team? Answering this sort of question is what they're paid for, and they're the ones who will have the best data to work with.

Comment: @keshlam - Yes, I have. See more details about that in the edit to the question.

Comment: What I show above is a table indicating the contents of a CSV file that I attempted to upload. It is in the same format as CSV files that I uploaded successfully in the past.

Comment: If Yahoo isn't supporting their service, maybe you need to find a service that is supported?

Comment: Even if someone else wanted to spend the time trying to debug Yahoo's system, we would need an actual copy of the failing file to examine for possible errors. Though the unhelpful "try again later" message strongly suggests that this is a problem inside Yahoo, in which case all you can do is keep trying and hope they eventually fix it. Yahoo staff would be able to tell you more. Not a lot we can do that you aren't already trying.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a product support question rather than a personal finance question. Take it to the product's own discussion board, if you can't get help from their support desk ... or consider using another product.

Answer (score 3):

I got an [answer to this over on *Web Applications*](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/173750/why-cant-i-upload-a-portfolio-to-yahoo-finance/#173756). The problem was the date format. It used to work to submit that as "yyyy mm dd". But sometime in early 2023, the requirement changed and it now has to be submitted as a number, for which "yyyymmdd" works. With that change, my uploads worked.